# MySQL: Selecting Twice from One Table

Tags: mysql

Apologies for this vague title...  I'm having a hard time even summarizing what I'm trying to do.  I suspect it's a very basic SQL function but I lack the technical vocabulary for it.

I have a table with three fields:  person_id (number), person_name (string), best_friend_id (number).

A couple of sample records might be: (1, "John", 2) and (2, "Mary", 3).  These sample records state that Person 1 is John, whose best friend is Person 2; and, that Person 2 is Mary, whose best friend is some other Person with id 3.

Is it possible to write a SELECT statement for a MySQL database that would show both the person's name and the name of the best friend for each record in the table?  Such as, (1, "John", 2, "Mary"); (2, "Mary", 3, "Fred"); and so on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table to itself,

```
SELECT tbl1.person_id, 
       tbl1.person_name, 
       tbl1.best_friend_id, 
       tbl2.person_name 
FROM table_name tbl1
LEFT JOIN table_name tbl2 ON tbl1.person_id = tbl2.best_friend_id
```

Comment: Thank you!  This looks like it will work perfectly.  On a hunch, I also googled "mysql self join" and found this link, http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/ which suggested a similar answer.